# How to create offline html document with charts?

Tags: html, report, offline

I have to create programmatically offline html report with bar chart and maybe other types of graph using java.
What is appropriate Javascript/canvas framework to use in this case?
Strong requirement is one file for one report.

Answer (score 0):

If you have alot of charts and graphs to display and need to keep it in HTML format, keep in mind that MS excel can export and save files as .html files and can be viewed offline. All that is needed is a browser.

Comment: Sorry, I wan't precisely. I mean programmatically creation